# How to make a condition that checks the binary image array and finds the zero row from the center?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, binary-image

Python: I want to make a condition that checks the binary image array and finds the zero rows from the center. if zero rows not available in the center then print the statement "Zero rows not available"...!

image:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcUwa.png)

```
Array= [[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0]
  [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
  [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
  [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
  [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
  [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
  [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
[255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255]
[255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255]]
```

What I have Tried:

```py
img = np.array(img) 
moment = cv2.moments(img)   
X = int(moment ["m10"] / moment["m00"])
Y = int(moment ["m01"] / moment["m00"])
print(X,Y)
u = X ,Y
imagesE = cv2.findNonZero(u)
print(imagesE)
```

These are the Zero Rows. I want to find these zero rows from the center of an array through condition...!

```
[[
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]]
```

Then I simply use the boolean operator "!" with `cv2.findNonZero`. But did not find require output.

Comment: Please post you textual information as text (no screenshot) and show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: What is "the zero row from the center"?

Comment: @DanMašek I want to make a condition that is used to find zero rows from the center just like in Array; there are some zero rows in a center. I only want to find out the location of that zero values...!

Comment: Is this a 1-D array or a 2-D array? Your example array is not completely full if it's 2-D, so I have to ask. Next: do you expect the indices of the rows of zeroes, or their (not very interesting) contents?

Comment: @joanis! it is a 2D array and I want both; the indices of the rows of zeroes, or their contents

Comment: What do you consider a center? To me, when talking about an image, the center would be at half of the width/height (the point where the diagonals cross). However, you seem to be using moments to get the center.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, you are right. But if you see my reference binary image, then you may understand that I just want to find out the middle rows of the binary image (having Zero's value) and it is only possible with a condition like this "There will be rows of zero's in the middle of image array". I don't have any idea about this So I just try to find out the middle of an array using moments. Maybe I am wrong. that's why I asked this question. THANK YOU!

Comment: OK If you're working with a rectangular image, then it would seem sufficient to just use height to determine the middle row. You would need to define how to handle the situation where the middle is in between two rows (i.e. what is the center row of an image with 2 rows?). Once you're done that, Mark's answer will provide the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what a *"zero row from the centre"* is, but you can get the sums of all the rows with:

```
rowSums = np.sum(array, axis=1)
```

Comment: Ok, @Mark Setchell. Thank You for your answer.

Comment: Mark, he wants to find all rows starting with the center row and working outwards that have all zero column values. So your row sums give him a way to determine that.